# how to set up ejabberd cluster?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am using 2 ec2 instances on which ejabberd 13.12 is installed . I am following  [this guide](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html) for setting up cluster. On Second node when i run the command -

```
 erl -sname ejabberd \

-mnesia dir '"/var/lib/ejabberd/"' \

-mnesia extra_db_nodes "['ejabberd@first']" \

-s mnesia
```

On First Node error occurs -

```
Application ejabberd started on node ejabberd@ejabberdn1
dets: file "/var/lib/ejabberd/schema.DAT" not properly closed, repairing ...

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 27-May-2014::07:11:59 ===
 Supervisor: {local,mnesia_kernel_sup}
 Context:    child_terminated
 Reason:     killed
 Offender:   [{pid,<0.152.0>},
              {name,mnesia_locker},
              {mfargs,{mnesia_locker,start,[]}},
              {restart_type,permanent},
              {shutdown,3000},
              {child_type,worker}]


=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 27-May-2014::07:11:59 ===
 Supervisor: {local,mnesia_kernel_sup}
 Context:    shutdown
 Reason:     reached_max_restart_intensity
 Offender:   [{pid,<0.152.0>},
              {name,mnesia_locker},
              {mfargs,{mnesia_locker,start,[]}},
              {restart_type,permanent},
              {shutdown,3000},
              {child_type,worker}]
```

It gives error of mnesia network partitioning on second node. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: what are you trying to say?

Comment: Shut down both servers, then delete all the DAT files on both machines, then try again.

Comment: where are these files present in ubuntu?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot i have deleted all files from /var/lib/ejabberd/ but then also is is showing the same problem.

Comment: You're not doing something weird like having the same `/var/lib/ejabberd` shared between your two nodes, right? Your Mnesia DB is corrupted. Either it's currently corrupt and you're not cleaning it well enough before retrying, or it's getting corrupted by something you're doing. Look for other errors earlier in the logs. Consider running each node under a VM to make sure it's not getting clobbered by some other process you have lying around.

Comment: When i run both nodes independently , they runs fine. I don't know what is happening when i try to connect them.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Dude. Help me help you. I wrote you a paragraph of troubleshooting suggestions. Try each one, then edit the question to include what you tried (exactly) and what happened (exactly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I solved my problem. The problem is with Erlang OTP version. I was using Ejabberd 13.12 and Erlang OTP 15B1 . Inspite this combination is working good in local network but not working on AWS EC2. Now I Have replaced Erlang OTP version with OTP 17 and my cluster is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to clear your local database files and have ejabberd regenerate them after you have set up host names, etc.

I have got my cluster running by following [this](http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql) guide up to step 5 on both nodes, then (since I did not want to use this custom module for database sync) I went to [the guide](http://www.ejabberd.im/files/doc/guide.html#htoc28) you mentioned and did the database sync manually as you are currently trying to. (It still took me half a day to trace all errors, but with the above mentioned guides and googling error messages from the log files it finally worked out. ;) )

Comment: On local network the above method works good. The problem occurs when i make cluster on AWS ec2.

Comment: I have followed both the guides. But same problem occurred.

Comment: hm, ok, my cluster was actually running via VPN (worked fine + secure channel), but I have no experience outside local networks, sorry